# sqlalchemy UnmappedColumnError when inserting into many-to-many records

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following many to many relationship defined in my flask-sqlalchemy models:

```
class Course: 
    ...
    modules = db.relationship('Module', secondary=course_modules,
        primaryjoin=(course_modules.c.course_id == id),  
        secondaryjoin=(course_modules.c.module_id == id),
        backref=db.backref('courses', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
```

and the module_course Table object defined as:

```
course_modules=db.Table('course_modules',
    db.Column('course_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('course.id')),
    db.Column('module_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('module.id'))
)
```

When doing the following to create a record in this table I get a sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedColumnError:

```
module = module_service.get_by_id(1) # returns a Module instance
course.modules = [module] # course being a Course instance
course.modules.all()

sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedColumnError: Can't execute sync rule for  
source column 'course.id'; mapper 'Mapper|Module|module' does not map 
this column.  Try using an explicit `foreign_keys` collection which 
does not include destination column 'course_modules.module_id' 
(or use a viewonly=True relation).
```

When I remove the **primaryjoin** and **secondaryjoin** lines from the db relationship and use this method I do not hit the same error and the data does get inserted.

Why is it that including primary and secondary join conditions causes insert to break? Is there an alternative method for inserting data into many-to-many relationships that I should be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this code:

```
modules = db.relationship('Module', secondary=course_modules,
    primaryjoin=(course_modules.c.course_id == id),  
    secondaryjoin=(course_modules.c.module_id == id),
```

`id` in both primaryjoin and secondaryjoin refers due to scoping to Course.id. You should reference the correct `id` columns explicitly, e.g.:

```
modules = db.relationship('Module', secondary=course_modules,
    primaryjoin=(course_modules.c.course_id == Course.id),  
    secondaryjoin=(course_modules.c.module_id == Module.id),
```

Comment: Would it be possible to expand a bit on this? I dont quite get where the id's have been incorrectly referenced.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Why the negative votes? This solved the problem for me. Well, it _would_ give an error on the id qualified with the class name that is being defined--in the given example, the `Course.id`--, but that one does not need to be qualified.

Comment: @FrancescoMarchetti-Stasi  What did you do to solve the error on `Course` in `Course.id`?

Comment: I myself solved the problem this way: `Lambda:Course.id == course_modules.c.course_id`